# Sending and Receiving data with Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have two clients, Client 1 sends data to our Node.js & Express back-end, and the back-end emits an event that only Client 2 can receive it. After, Client 2 receives the data and displays it.

Below are the codes for Client 1:

```
var socket = io();
  socket.emit("match_package", {user_uid, match_uid, room_id, user_data});
```

Node.js Express server:

```
var tech = io.of("/");
tech.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("match_package", (data) => {
    var match_uid = data.match_uid;
    var room_id = data.room_id;
    socket.emit(match_uid, room_id);
    socket.emit("1", "hello");
  }
}
```

Client 2:

```
var socket = io();
socket.on('connect', () => {
  socket.on(user_uid, (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  socket.emit("1", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
})
```

The `match_uid` from the back-end is the same as the `user_uid` in Client 2 (verified). That is how that event is only visible to Client 2. But somehow on Client 2, the `console.log` are not displaying any data. I can guarantee that the data are received fine in the back-end. But somehow Client 2 does not receive it.

I even emitted a dummy event "1" from the back-end. That is not received by Client 2 either.

What did I do wrong here?

Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store all the socket.ids in array, then you can get that socket.id with the receiver name whenever you are sending message.

[Here you can find what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40174621/8637561)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the link, do you have any idea why my codes don't work?